# Firebase rules for a single authenticated user

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have created a small app which uses Firebase as its database for my portfolio.  A lot of the website renders a different view whether an authenticated user is logged and I would like to have one account that has the ability to log in and would be authenticated but would not have permission to write.  My current rules are as follows:

```
"rules": {
  ".read": true,
  ".write": "auth != null", }
```

I know this allows anyone to read the data (which I want) but I am wondering if there is a way to "trick" my react app into thinking a user, with an example uid of "Example123", is authenticated but if that user tries to write it fails?

I have tried something like:

```
"rules": {
  ".read": true,
  ".write": "auth != Example123", }
```

but firebase did not like that.  Is it possible to do what I am wanting using firebase rules or would I need to figure out a different approach?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do as follow:

Create a node `users` in your database, under which you will store the specific user(s) with its (their) User UID, like:

```
- users
    - Lt7kif73eL58dFCYcmeEfOzUl2n1  <- User UID
      - restrictedRights: true
      - name: xxxxxx
```

and write your rule as follow

```
".write": "auth != null && !root.child('users').hasChild(auth.uid)"
```

Of course you should add this rule to your database:

```
"users": {
        ".read": ....,
        ".write": false   
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you very much for this.  It has also helped me understand how Firebase rules work as well.